# Data structure redis

Tags: php, redis

I am a newbie to redis.
Here is my doubt.

Let's say I have 100 records from a MySQL table.

```
id | name | surname | age | username | password | amount | currency

1  | nick | goean   | 29  | nick_go  | nickpass | 120

2  | joe | keve   | 30  | keve_joe  | kevepass | 110
```

I need to store this in redis and should use to query by age and currency,
actually I should get all the possible combinations to query from redis.

Can anyone help me with an example data structure for the same?

Comment: Can't you just use mysql?

Comment: The common approach is to use a Hash for storing your rows and a Set per searchable attribute (column). You can either use an ORM to abstract access to Redis, or implement it in code yourself.